# How do you filter an airtable record that contains a given string, but may also contain others?

Tags: javascript, node.js, airtable

Using the airtable api's filterByFormula method I can query and select records that contain one specific item (string). However, this query only returns the records that have ONLY that specific string.

Searching the airtable api formula documentation here:
https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-Field-Reference
yields no answers.

What I have:

```
base('Table').select({
    view: 'Main View',
    filterByFormula: `Column = "${myFilter}"`
}).firstPage(function(err, records) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); reject( err ); }

    records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log(record.get('Another Column'));

    });
```

Again, this returns records that have ONLY myFilter, and not records that contain any additional values in the given Column.

edit: airtable refers to these columns as 'multiselect' field types.

Comment: Could you not use the `SEARCH` or `FIND` functions with a `>= 0`? like `\`SEARCH("${myFilter}", Column) >= 0\``?

Comment: Throw that in an answer so I can accept it. That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that airtable has support for the js equivalent of `indexOf` in the form of [`SEARCH`](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-Field-Reference#text_functions). From the docs:

> **SEARCH(find_string, within_string, position)**
> Returns the index of the first occurrence of find_string in within_string, starting at position. Position is 0 by default.

As such, we can use the following as our search filter value

```
filterByFormula: `SEARCH("${myFilter}", Column) > 0`
```

This will search our `Column` for the presence of `myFilter` and return any result were `myFilter` is located at some position within the `Column`.

*NB:It may be worth caveating, that your `myFilter` property is probably best to have a minimum character count of at least 2 for performance. The docs also do not specify an option for case insensitivity, so you may wish to wrap both `Column` and `"${myFilter}"` in a `LOWER()` function, if you want to return results regardless of upper or lower case characters. For example*

```
filterByFormula: `SEARCH(LOWER("${myFilter}"), LOWER(Column)) > 0`
```

Comment: Great touch adding in the wrapper for ignoring case.

Comment: You are off by one. `SEARCH` seems to return 0 when the string is not found. But thanks for the `LOWER` idea :)

Comment: @bijancn Very strange that 0 would be returned when a string is not found. If the string is found at the first letter does it also return 0 or 1?

Comment: @haxxxton if the find_string is found at the beginning of the within_string, the function returns 1